# How do I copy pandas nested column to another DF?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, delta-lake

We have some data in a Delta source which has nested structures. For this example we are focusing on a particular field from the Delta named `status` which has a number of sub-fields: `commissionDate`, `decommissionDate`, `isDeactivated`, `isPreview`, `terminationDate`.

In our transformation we currently read the Delta file in using PySpark, convert the DF to pandas using `df.toPandas()` and operate on this pandas DF using the pandas API. Once we have this pandas DF we would like to access its fields without using row iteration.

The data in Pandas looks like the following when queried using `inventory_df["status"][0]` (i.e. `inventory_df["status"]` is a list):

```
Row(commissionDate='2011-07-24T00:00:00+00:00', decommissionDate='2013-07-15T00:00:00+00:00', isDeactivated=True, isPreview=False, terminationDate=None)
```

We have found success using row iteration like:

```
unit_df["Active"] = [
        not row["isDeactivated"] for row in inventory_df["status"]
    ]
```

but we have to use a row iteration each time we want to access data from the `inventory_df`. This is more verbose and is less efficient.

We would love to be able to do something like:

```
unit_df["Active"] = [
        not inventory_df["status.isDeactivated"]
    ]
```

which is similar to the Spark destructuring approach, and allows accessing all of the rows at once but there doesn't seem to be equivalent pandas logic.

The data within PySpark has a format like `status: struct<commissionDate:string,decommissionDate:string,isDeactivated:boolean,isPreview:boolean,terminationDate:string>` and we can use the format mentioned above, selecting a subcolumn like `df.select("status.isDeactivated")`.

How can this approach be done using pandas?

Comment: Each inner DataFrame only has one row per outer row, or do they have multiple rows?

Comment: Each only has one row per outer row. I've put a snippet of it in the post, in what is now the first code segment.

Comment: `Row(commissionDate='2011-07-24T00:00:00+00:00', ...)` is a `pyspark.sql.Row` object, not a `pandas.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you to where you think you are:

```
unit_df["Active"] = unit_df["Active"].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.asDict()))
```

From here I would do:

```
unit_df = pd.concat([pd.concat(unif_df["Active"], ignore_index=True), unit_df], axis=1)
```

Which would get you a singular `pd.DataFrame`, now with columns for `commissiondate`, `decomissiondate`, etc.

Comment: Thank you @BeRT2me! Using apply was the breakthrough needed. I ended up being able to do something like `unit_df["Active"] = inventory_df["status"].apply(lambda x: not x["isDeactivated"], 1)` which seems to be giving me the correct result.